# Error while changing job_class attribute in jobs

Tags: oracle, jobs, job-scheduling

I have created a job_class having logging level as FULL.
SQL syntax for the same is :

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job_class(job_class_name => 'full_job_class',
                                  comments       => 'Job class having logging level as full.',
                                  logging_level  => dbms_scheduler.logging_full);
END;
```

Now I am trying to change attribute for all the listed JOB in my DB to set its job_class attribute to the newly created job_class.

SQL syntax for the same:

```
DECLARE
  vs_statement VARCHAR2(100);

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT '''' || owner || '.' || job_name || '''' as job_name
    FROM dba_scheduler_jobs d
    WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'DBSNMP', 'ORACLE_OCM', 'SYSTEM');
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN c1 LOOP
       execute immediate ('BEGIN dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(NAME => '||rec.job_name||', attribute => ''JOB_CLASS'', VALUE => ''FULL_JOB_CLASS''); END;');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

But while running this code I am getting now and than below error:

```
ORA-27470: failed to re-enable "WEB"."REFRESH_PERFORMANCE" after making requested change
ORA-27476: "SYS"."FULL_JOB_CLASS" does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line 4648
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 3052
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

But when I am executing one at a time to change job's attribute to set its job_class then I don't get any error.

Comment: I don't know, never did that. However, does CaSE MaTTeR? What happens if you use all CAPS while referencing FULL_JOB_CLASS?

Comment: @KaushikNayak no, because while I am executing it individually and setting its attribute I didn't encountered this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you grant the `EXECUTE` object privilege as SYS to the schema attempting to make the change.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SYS.FULL_JOB_CLASS TO {JOB_OWNER};
```